# sql server how to default nvarhcar column to GUID if it's null or empty

Tags: sql-server

If I have a nvarchar column in sql server 2012, how do I default the value to a GUID when the value is null or empty space?

To be more clear: 
Not only it should work when people do:

```
INSERT INTO table(second_column) VALUES('test')
```

It should also work if people do:

```
INSERT INTO table(column_with_default, second_column) VALUES('', 'test')
```

I tried to set the default to

> LEFT(NEWID(), 36)

but it doesn't work...

When I insert to the table with 'NULL' for that column, it's just NULL (same with '').

Comment: What do you mean setting the default to LEFT(NEWID(), 36) doesn't work? What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT 2: According to your comments I change my answer

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(ID NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID()
                 ,TestData NVARCHAR(MAX));
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TestTrigger ON dbo.Test
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Test(ID,TestData)
    SELECT CASE WHEN i.ID IS NULL OR i.ID='' THEN CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) ELSE i.ID END,i.TestData
    FROM inserted AS i;
END
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test(ID,TestData) VALUES(NULL,'test with NULL');
INSERT INTO dbo.Test(ID,TestData) VALUES('','test with EMPTY');
INSERT INTO dbo.Test(ID,TestData) VALUES('abc','test with real data');

SELECT * FROM Test;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Test;
```

The result

```
69604546-47BD-4E0D-9924-FAD39054BFFD    test with NULL
D9F38DB0-1155-464B-89C7-43C2CE8381BF    test with EMPTY
abc                                     test with real data
```

Comment: @AllenZhang, see my edit. We were both typing at the same time... :-)

Comment: So is there a way to default empty string to a GUID?

Comment: @AllenZhang, look at my new answer. The trigger is called "instead of" the normal insert operation...

Comment: It isn't very flexible. But it answered the question:)

Comment: @AllenZhang, Thank you for the acceptance... May I give you a tiny hint? Acceptance and upvote are two different steps. As you accepted this answer I think you consider it to be helpfull, don't you? So please: Start to be very generous with your votes 'cause this is how SO works. People like me are addicted to reputation points :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NEWID()` in a Default Value constraint. If the field is not large enough then use `LEFT(NEWID(),<field-length>)` as the constraint expression.